# Generic method in java not returning the type expected

Tags: java, generics

I have created a generic method toList():

```
public static <T> List<T> toList(T... args){
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T t : args) {
            list.add(t);
        }

        if(list instanceof Comparable<?>){
            System.out.println("The list was considered a list of Comparable objects");
        }
        if(list instanceof Serializable){
            System.out.println("The list was considered a list of Serializable objects");
        }
        if(list instanceof Object){
            System.out.println("The list was considered a list of Object class' objects");
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I am calling this method like :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Generics.<Comparable>toList(1,2,"3"));
  }
```

I was expecting that since I have supplied the type Comparable, the first if condition would hold true and o/p would be first Comparable, then Object. 
But to my surprise, control didn't go in first if and the o/p was Serializable and then Object.

Can anyone throw some light on the reason behind this?
Also I am not clear with the concept of applying T in the method signature after the access modifier.

We have mentioned the access specifier, modifier and the return type. What is the need of supplying T ?

Comment: As for you second question, you need to declare <T> after the access modifier on order to use it later in the method signature.  If it was NOT there, then I think the compiler would look to an enclosing scope (for example a parameterized class) .   But if you don't declare T as some sort of generic, how is the Compiler supposed to interpret List<T> that immediately follows?   It would have to assume that a "T" was a class that was defined somewhere, but it doesn't have an import for it.

Comment: @Teto So in a layman's language, can we say that T simply tells the compiler not to think of T as a class and start searching for it. Rather just    an indication that T is some type which would be supplied later and that the list will hold objects of that type?

Comment: Yes. think that is a good way to say it.

Comment: @dpr done :) and sorry as I forgot to do that earlier...

Comment: Thanks. And there's no need to say sorry for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are performing your assertions on the list object and not on the elements of the list.

```
list instanceof Comparable<?>
```

This will only return `true` if the list itself would implement the `Comparable` interface.
As `ArrayList` is serializable and of course is an object the other two conditions will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: +1 Good answer, but to clarify, the type parameter `<T>` refers to the type of the _elements_ of the list not the list itself.  `java.util.List<...>` extends only `Collection` and `Iterable` but NOT `Comparable`.

Comment: @dpr Oh yes, I was checking if the list object is an instance of Comparable which is not true and hence the o/p. Thanks for pointing the mistake.
But even with list.get(0) instanceof , the o/p is Comparable , then Serializable, then Object. Should it not consider the elements as type of Comparable and Object when I have explicitly mentioned the type while calling. If this is happening because of type erasure, what is the use of using type parameters then when at runtime it is going to erase the type?

Comment: The element at index 0 of your list is an `Integer` (automatically boxed by the JVM from the `int`). `Integer` implements `Comparable`, `Serializable` and is of course an instance of `Object`. Even if the generic is evaluated to be `Object` only - because of the different types you provided - the instances in your list will of course keep their original types.

Comment: Now this is a bit confusing. I am passing three parameters, 2 of type Integer(after boxing) and third of type String, but at the same time, I am indicating the compiler to consider them of type Comparable(all three of them because they qualify also, right?). Still while it is taking as Serializable, Comparable and Object. If it had to take all the possible types into account, what for do we specify the type explicitly then?  
2nd, if it is happening because of the type erasure at run-time, what is the whole idea of using the type parameters in the first place?

Comment: Why does the compiler throw a warning when we do not specify the type explicitly and then when we are supplying the type, it is not considering it?

Comment: Generics is only a convenience feature that was introduced to avoid exhaustive casting all over the code when using collections, nothing more and nothing less. To support backward compatibility types are erased at runtime. Maybe you want to read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me what you are trying to do is test the element type, `T`, inside your method. Because of [type erasure (follow the link)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) you cannot do this. The actual type of `T` is only known at compile time, not on runtime. On runtime, inside the method, Java will just think `T` is `Object`.